# Add 7 days to a specific date when there are multiple other dates

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working with a Google Sheet and attempting to script a automated due date.  I will readily and freely admit that I am a total noob and have barely recently had some success implementing scripts, but can't get this one to work.

Specifically, Column R has a date received.  Column T needs the due date which would be 7 calendar days from the date received.  Multiple other columns have other dates in them so the script has to specifically look to R to avoid changing or calculating off other dates.

I am using the script below.  (Multiple scripts are running hence the function name.  there is one onEdit(e) function running the scripts).  Nothing is happening though with the script - nothing appears in column T.    Any help is appreciated.

```
function script5(e) {
  
var Date = sheet.getRange(18);  
var Day = [Date.getCell(0,3). getValue()];

Day = Number(Day)+7; //change "7" for the amount of days you want
Date.setValue(Day);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets and spend sometime learning the pretty basics of JavaScript. P.S. `sheet` is undefined, the parameters of getRange are wrong, `Date` should not be used as variable name because this will overwrite the built-in JavaScript `Date` object

Comment: I had copied this script from someone else.  Thanks for the corrections though.

Answer (score 0):

#### Add days to a Date()

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const days = sh.getRange("A1").getValue();//put 7 in A1
  const dt = new Date();
  const dat = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate() + days)
  sh.getRange("A2").setValue(dat);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't solve my problem.